# How do I use deep selector on a group of selectors

Tags: html, css, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div id="content" v-html="field.content"></div>
</template>

<style scoped>
#content >>> .table, .general, .picture, .cover, .formula, .flow, .default, .other {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

As the code above. I'm using vue.js, and will insert some html code dynamically in . I want to use the deep selector (>>>) like the code above, but only the first selector (.table) will work when I test my code.

Is there any way to use deep selector on group selectors?

I google this with key words like "css deep selector group selector", "css >>> group selector", "css >>> complex selector" and so on, but finding no similar question and sulotions. Did I enter a inappropriate keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should repeat the selector each time as down below.

```
#content >>> .table, 
#content >>> .general, 
#content >>> .picture {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Or, you can use :where selector

```
#content >>> :where(.table, .general, .picture) {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks. the first solved my problem. i also tried the second one but it doesn't work in project. IDEA report an error on ":where". it says "Unknown pseudo selector 'where'"

Comment: Maybe you could try this instead. #content >>> *:where(.table, .general, .picture)

Comment: i just did some google and testing and found that `*:where()` and `:where()` both are ok. but  it seams to be a new feature and not all explorors support it. i use chrome, version 86, for development. it support this feature since version 72. but until now, users have to enable the feature explictly.

Comment: Make sense! I didn't know that. Then, this is best that use the first option for best browser support. Longer but safe!

Answer (score -2):

```html
#content .table,
#content .general,
#content .picture,
#content .cover,
#content .formula,
#content .flow,
#content .default,
#content .other {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: thank you for yours answer. but it seams that your code can't render a dynamically inserted html code.